# How do I stop the text from appearing then disappearing a second later, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get text to show up in a div by using

```
  function frenchBread(){
      var div = document.getElementById("orderBox");

      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "French Bread";
  }
```

I have created an inpute type = image that will use this function with an onclick event. It works, however, the text shows up in the div for a second then disappears. I'm not sure if this problem is relevant to the fact that this div is inside of a table, too. Sorry, I'm somewhat of a newbie at javascript and html.

```
      <td>
        <div class = "order">
          <p>Your Order:</p>
          <p id = "orderBox"></p>
        </div>
      </td>
```

The above is the part of the table that the div is in.

```
<input type = "image" class = "items" src ="FrenchBread.png" value = "frenchBread" onclick = "frenchBread()">
```

The above is where I called the function.

Comment: Nothing about that code will cause the text to disappear. (Or, for that matter, appear in the first place since you never call the function).

Comment: Do you have anything inside `orderBox` that you don't want to override when you modify its content? I am asking because you are doing `.innerHTML = .innerHTML + ....`. Without seeing how you are calling the above function, I can only say that you could try to simply set the content by doing `div.innerHTML = 'French Bread';`.

Comment: No, there's really nothing in there, I just want text to be added. However, I want to be able to continue to append more text, too.

Answer (score 1):

An image input is a server side image map. Clicking on it will submit the form it is in. This will cause a new page to be loaded.

Use a button instead.

```
<button type="button" onclick="..."><img ...></button>
```

Apply CSS to remove any borders and background colour as desired.